# Configuring f5 to retry requests on timeout

Tags: f5-big-ip

I have a pool of servers and f5 BIG-IP loadbalancer in front of them. I want to configure the following behaviour: if one server haven't answered on http request in e.g. 1 second request will be resent to another server. Is it possible?

Comment: You might be able to tweak [gor](https://github.com/buger/gor) to meet your needs, but I haven't seen any commercial load balancers that offer replays.

Answer (score 2):

https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iRules.HTTP__retry.ashx

that would probably be your answer.

Comment: URL-only answers are encouraged.  Maybe you could quote a line or two?

Comment: According to the docs, HTTP::retry command is valid only inside HTTP_RESPONSE and  HTTP_RESPONSE_DATA. But in my case these events will not be triggered.

Comment: There's a reason URL-only answers are not encouraged. The URLs go dead after some time.